# How can I get a div content to print in the center of a 8.5x11 sheet of paper?

Tags: css, html, printing

I echo out information into a div and I have a jQuery print element to print that div. But the paper is always printed off-center. How can I manage to design the div to print in the center of the page? is there an exact height/width to follow?

This is my div css class

```
.contract {
   align: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;  
   width: 800px;
   background-color: #fff;
   clear: both;
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can understand, you can set align="center" into div. However you should also post your code and the screenshot (in this case) for better response.

Answer (score 2):

Use this CSS

```
@media print {
    #printDiv{
         position:absolute;
         width:300px;
         height:300px;
         z-index:15;
         top:50%;
         left:50%;
         margin:-150px 0 0 -150px;
    }
}
```

Value of Margin should be 50% of the width and height value

Comment: Not very helpful without an explanation of why

Comment: @Vignesh Sakthivel, Please review my post as I just added my css code. This code if for the printable section that I need it centred

Comment: Joe Phillips: This css code will center align the div both vertically and horizontally. Adding @media print will ensure that this css is applied only to Printing and not for displaying in screen

Comment: Mike, I think, the css code you have used is for displaying it in the screen.. The code I have mentioned will center align the div both vertically and horizontally

Comment: It seems like when clicking the print button to print "CSS" is ignored completly! It print with no formatting at all. Is there a way I can use the same setting to print and also display? I want it to print the same way it display on the screen

Answer (score -1):

there is no css `align` property. try `margin:0 auto;`, however without seeing the rest of your document it's quite impossible to tell.